# Как скомпилировать проект в динамическую библиотеку Linux (.so)?

Tags: c++, linux, c, компиляция, плагин

Проект:https://github.com/pBlueG/Socket/tree/v0.1a

Я пробовал скомпилировать его, но вылетает ошибка:

```
moono@moono-VirtualBox:~/Рабочий стол/Socket-0.1a/socket$ make
    gcc -c -m32 -O3 -fPIC -w -DLINUX -Wall -I../SDK/amx/ ../SDK/amx/*.c
    In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:27:0,
                     from ../SDK/amx/getch.c:4:
    /usr/include/features.h:367:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
    compilation terminated.
    makefile:9: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all»
    make: *** [all] Ошибка 1
```

Comment: *Рабочий стол* — на будущее: компиляцией лучше заниматься в каталогах, не содержащих в пути к ним символов за пределами ascii. потому как могут появляться совершенно непонятные ошибки, из текста которых никак не следует, что вызваны они именно не-ascii-символами в пути к сборочному каталогу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

makefile находится в подкаталоге socket проекта Socket, именно оттуда его нужно запускать, а он уже соберет весь проект вместе с библиотеками. При этом у вас должен быть установлен gcc и g++, запускаемые именно с такими именами.

И не стоит брать этот проект за образец в дальнейшем.

Comment: *именно оттуда его нужно запускать* — не обязательно: `$ make -C каталог-где-находится-makefile` и процесс *make*  после запуска изменит свой текущий каталог на указанный.

Comment: g++ нужно было установить, спасибо